# Rails won't recognize setting a variable to 'false'?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-migrations

I have the following (simplified) model and migration:

Model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_readonly :contacted

  validates :contacted, :inclusion => { :in => [true, false] }

  def set_contacted
    self.contacted = true
  end

  def unset_contacted
    # self.contacted = false
    self.contacted = "0"
  end
end
```

Migration:

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.boolean :contacted,     :null => false, :default => false

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

As you can kind of see in the comment in my model, setting the variable `contact` to false results in an error - I can only set it to "0".  Why?  I don't see how "false" would violate the null constraint, right?

**Edit:**
For clarification, I am using PostgreSQL and ActiveRecord.  The error that I'm getting is this:

```
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/validations.rb:56:in 'save!' Validation failed: ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid)
```

I get that error even if I remove the "validates" statement from my model, and even if I remove the NULL constraint from the migration.  It's something to do with setting the value of the attribute to be false.  Is there some odd constraint on ActiveRecord booleans?

Comment: What database system are you using? Also, please add the error message to your question.

Comment: I'm using Postgresql.  I get a whole string of messages basically saying that ActiveRecord "save!" failed.

Comment: Even if you don't think it'll help, it's always a good idea to paste your error message into the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No one seems able to solve this, but it' no longer an issue for me.  My model is better served by using a state_machine gem, so I removed this field altogether.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit difficult answering your question without having the specific error information.

First I'd change `attr_readonly` to `attr_accessible` - So the field will be updatable.

Secondly, I'd re-write your method:

```
  def unset_contacted
    self.contacted = false
    self.save! # Saving your methods (the ! is for throwing an exception if it fails).
  end
```